# Javascript Function execution stops unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
alert("setprice before");
$(".quantity").each($(".quantity").attr("disabled", false));
alert("setprice after");
```

I have a form with a number of input fields of class `.quantity` which are enabled once a required field is changed.

```
$(".quantity").each($(".quantity").attr("disabled", false));
```

The alert call before this line works fine, and the call itself does work as expected but the alert message after the call doesn't appear. Nothing I put after this line works but the line itself does execute as expected.

Something must be breaking but I can't see what. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you look in developer tools console for the error generated on line 2

Comment: You don't need `$.each` just use `$(".quantity").prop("disabled", false);`

Comment: @Tushar - assuming you have jQuery loaded (in both cases)

Comment: I suggest you to look at the browser console(can be opened by `F12` on most browsers) and check what he has to say. You'll most probably get the error there and can be solved easily by peeking in the JS/jQ documentation.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks everybody.  The console didn't show any errors I could see but I'm new at this.

Comment: @AzzaClazza you'll probably get an error like `Uncaught TypeError: c.call is not a function(…)` make sure you're console doesn't have a filter applied which doesn't show errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery.each` accepts a function as argument, so it should be:

```
$(".quantity").each(function() {
  $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Also, to remove an attribute you have to use `.removeAttr()` function.

As pointed by @Tushar, if you only want to change an attribute of multiple elements, you can simply do:

```
$(".quantity").prop("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method accepts a function. But you're passing it a jQuery object instead.

Your code should be simply

```
$(".quantity").attr("disabled", false);
```

Because jQuery setter methods iterates over all elements in the collection by default.

or `$(".quantity").prop('disabled', false)` as mentioned in comments.

Unhandled errors stops script execution which is why you're not seeing the later alert.